# Is it better to host the MX record for Google Apps at Network Solutions or web hosting service?

Tags: hosting, mx-record

A client has been hosting their MX Record for Google Apps with a web hosting service. The MX record has been handled by the web hosting service too. They are moving their web site to a new hosting service. So the question has come up, is it better to host the MX Record with Network Solutions or the new web hosting service? The arguments either way so far, have been that if they are with the web hosting service they have CPANEL and support is good to help if needed. The other argument has been that the MX Record should be hosted by Network Solutions who is hosting the DNS for their domain, because is for some reason the web hosting service was down, e-mail for the company would still work. Also, in the future if the web site is moved to yet another web hosting service, e-mail will not be impacted because Network Solutions would be hosting the MX Record.

Anyone have experience either way or thoughts?

Comment: MX record is part of DNS.  It can't be hosted separately from the A and AAAA records.

Comment: Thanks, Stark. You are correct! I didn't know that. I guess the way people do this is register a similar domain with Network Solutions and then use a hosting service for their website.

Answer (score 0):

Generally the web hosting companies give you their nameserver's FQDN. All you need to do is to put those (generally two in the form of ns1 and ns2) in your domain control panel. Its easy to do this because they generally take care of all the entries (A, MX) for you. 
If you go this route, you'll need to explicitly ask them to change the MX values and point them to google's since you are not utilizing their mail services.

Since Network Solutions is providing you a nameserver entry, you can just to it yourself rather that depending on them. As you yourself mentioned, the benefit is that you'll not see whatever small downtime in emails whenever you choose to switch domains in future (its not difficult to prevent that though).
In this case, all you'll need is to ask is the A entry (IP address) of the webhost. Also make sure to point any sub-domains that you have (www, mail etc.)

Comment: I ended up chatting with technical support for the web hosting service, and found out the MX Record has to be hosted with them, not Network Solutions if the domain is the same. Google Apps will also queue the e-mail until a service is back in service, like if it's being rebooted.

Answer (score 0):

The happy ending is that I am hosting the MX Record with the Web hosting service. You can't have Network Solutions host the MX Record for the same exact domain that points to a web hosting service.